# Flutter - The Screen I have set wont show up

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

the screens wont be showing up and it will always be invalid index and thus my screens wont be showing up.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'notes_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class AppNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppNavigatorState createState() => _AppNavigatorState();
}

class _AppNavigatorState extends State<AppNavigator> {
  String imageUrl = ''; // Initialize imageUrl
  String fetchedCarId = '';
  int _currentIndex = 0; // Declare and initialize _currentIndex
  List<Widget> _screens = []; // Initialize _screens as an empty list

  Future<void> loadFirebaseData() async {
    try {
      // Fetch the carId from Firebase (replace 'your_car_id_path' with the actual path)
      final DataSnapshot carIdSnapshot = (await FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .reference()
          .child('your_car_id_path')
          .once()).snapshot;

    // Get the carId as a string
      final String carId = carIdSnapshot.value.toString();

      // Use the carId to construct the image filename
      final Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('images/car_image_$carId.jpg');

      // Fetch the image URL
      final String downloadURL = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();

      // Update the state with the fetched data
      setState(() {
        imageUrl = downloadURL; // Update the imageUrl when the download URL is available
        fetchedCarId = carId; // Update the carId
        _screens = [
          NotesScreen(imageUrl: imageUrl), // Pass the fetched imageUrl to NotesScreen
          Text('Reminder Screen'),
          Text('My Logo'),
          Text('Take Photo Screen'),
          Text('Gallery Screen'),
        ];
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any errors that occur while fetching the data
      print('Error loading Firebase data: $error');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeFirebase();
    // Fetch the image URL from Firebase Storage and update the state
    loadFirebaseData();
  }

  Future<void> initializeFirebase() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _currentIndex < _screens.length ? _screens[_currentIndex] : Text('Invalid Index'),
      ),
```

As can see from my code, I have 5 screens and by right when i start the program will start NotesScreen (which is the first element of the array).

I have try setting the index to -1 or 1 still wont help.